# How does jQuery treat comment elements?

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, comments, innerhtml

I always thought that jQuery operates only on DOM *elements*, that is those nodes that have `nodeType == 1`.

However I'm shocked that while creating HTML `$("<p> </p><!-- comment -->")` results in:

`[p, Comment { data=" comment ", length=21, nodeName="#comment", more...}]` (Firebug formatting)

I accepted some HTML by AJAX and a DOM Comment was created this way and passed somewhere to a function  that is applicable only to elements: `defaultView.getComputedStyle( elem, null )`

Is there some clean way out of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I always thought that jQuery operates only on DOM elements

Its selectors only *select* DOM elements. In your case, you're creating nodes from the HTML string you've provided. So jQuery parses the string and gives you back the nodes you're asking for.

To clean it, do a `.filter()`.

```
var els = $("<p> </p><!-- comment -->").filter(function() { 
                                                  return this.nodeType === 1; 
                                               });
```

Comment: Accepted because of the explanation.

Comment: @tillda: Just FYI, it is also a faster operation with the direct `this.nodeType === 1` test than running a `"*"` selector, though with a small set, it won't make a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, an interesting problem. After fiddling for a bit I found out that you can remove them using [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with the [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector) (`*`).

```
var a = $("<p></p><!-- comment -->");
console.log(a);
console.log(a.filter("*"));
```