# Does $() work differently in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am running the following JavaScript in both Firefox Developer Edition 38 and Internet Explorer 8 and 9.

```
console.log('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
console.log('jquery version = ' + $.fn.jquery);
var myHtmlString = "<!-- my comment -->" +
                      "<optgroup label='my label'>" +
                        "<option value='1'>option one</option>" +
                      "</optgroup>";

console.log($(myHtmlString));
console.log($(myHtmlString)[0]);
console.log($(myHtmlString)[1]);
console.log($(myHtmlString).length);
```

In Firefox, I get:

[image]

In IE, I get:

[image]

So, apparently in Firefox, an HTML comment is getting added in as an element of this object but in IE, it's not.  Why is this behaving this way, is there a bug, or is there another way I should be creating this object?

NOTE: I tried `$.parseHTML(myHtmlString)` but it does the same thing.

UPDATE: This answer [How does jQuery treat comment elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229076/how-does-jquery-treat-comment-elements/8229124#8229124) provides a potential workaround.

Comment: What is `[object Object]` in the IE log? Are you sure that's not your comment.

Comment: @JonathanWood Look at the differing output of `$(myHtmlString).length`

Comment: I can't find a reference, but comments created in javascript aren't supported in IE if I remember correctly, unless they are created with `document.createComment`, and I don't think jQuery uses that

Comment: Interesting that you're getting an `option` and not an `optGroup` node. Using `.innerHTML` in IE is pretty iffy to begin with. Use non-HTML was to create new DOM elements, whether native or jQuery.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So it depends on the browser you're using, but since you're passing in more than 1 simply tag, (as an example `$('<div>example html creation</div>')`) jQuery lets the *browser* handle the creation.

> If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as it is in the above example, **the actual creation of the elements is handled by the browser's .innerHTML mechanism**. In most cases, jQuery creates a new  element and sets the innerHTML property of the element to the HTML snippet that was passed in.

**[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2)**

Firefox for example is looking through each of your `< >` areas, and it finds 2. While IE doesn't care, and processes it all as 1 (hence the length 1).

*Long story short*, you're doing it fine. That's just internally how the browser is handling it, you don't have to worry about any of that!

Comment: If he wants a comment node, then it's not really fine. The fact that the browsers handle it differently *is* the problem. Not to mention that the wrong Element node is being returned.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS you are right: ` $(".my-class").html("<!-- test -->").html()` returns `""` in IE and `"<!-- test --> in chrome/firefox

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm misunderstanding about the question... but this seems like what the Question was.

Comment: You actually got a lot of hate from Meta. Deleting an answer because it has a downvote and then reanswer with the same answer.

Comment: [I'm so sorry about the Meta police](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289307/560648). Their behaviour is intolerable at times.

Comment: @Loko: It was a different answer then, bub.

Comment: I saw that, it was an accident actually I edited the entire answer (since I was off the original post) but didn't realize I could `undelete` it, instead I added a *new* answer. It looked confusing since you could see both answers and they looked identical that's all @Loko

Comment: It's not a problem, it was a mistake on my part, it looked like both answers were identical, but I should of never deleted the answer in the first place! I wasn't trying to escape downvotes or anything... I've been on stack for years! Downvotes are a part of life :) @LightningRacisinObrit